# Diferença e soma de coluna DATETIME

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, algoritmo, tabela-banco-de-dados

Tenho uma tabela chamada `chamado_processos` com a seguinte estrutura e dados

[image]

Como podem ver uma das colunas dessa tabela chamada `dt_processo` é um campo `DATETIME` e a coluna `tp_processo` define se o processo é de **início** ou **parada**.

Gostaria de calcular o tempo entre cada chamado considerando que **um único chamado** pode ter **mais de um processo de inicio** e **mais de um processo de parada**.

Esse chamado que mostrei na imagem tem `00:02:17` horas, minutos e segundos.

Comment: O que você já fez? Se tiver mais de um inicio vale o mais antigo? Se tiver mais de um termino vale o mais novo?

Comment: Está meio ampla o seu questionamento mediante **mais de um processo de inicio** e **mais de um processo de parada** simule isso também no seu questionamento? Como posso definir qual tirar/somar de qual?

Comment: O tempo de processo só será calculado se o último processo do chamado tiver o ``tp_processo = P``

Comment: Então se houver mais de um processo por exemplo um I e P, I e P, ele deverá somar os dois tempos e assim por diante, fui mais claro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outra forma de fazer isso e agrupando os valores por uma chave em comum e subtratir os valores tendo em conta se e inicio ou nao. Por isso a sua tabela de `chamado_processos` deveria ter uma coluna com uma valor igual para esses dois registos.

```
SELECT SUM(IF(tp_processo = 'P', `dt_processo`, 0)) - 
       SUM(IF(tp_processo = 'I', `dt_processo`, 0)) tempo 
FROM chamado_processos  
group by id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9488e)

Neste caso se nao houver processo de fim o resultado sera o tempo de inicio negativo

Comment: Obrigado! Fiz algumas pequenas modificações, me ajudou muito.

Answer (score 3):

**Soma de horas**

```
SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR, SUM (CONVERT (INT, LEFT (HORA, 2))) + (((SUM (CONVERT (INT, RIGHT (HORA, 2)))) - (SUM (CONVERT (INT, RIGHT (HORA, 2))) % 60)) / 60)) + ':' +  CONVERT (VARCHAR, SUM (CONVERT (INT, RIGHT (HORA, 2))) % 60) 
FROM TABELA
```

Está consulta faz a soma das horas utilizadas na tarefa.

**Diferença entre horas convertendo para quantidade de minutos**

```
SELECT 
ISNULL(DATEDIFF(Mi,'2011-12-01 02:05:00','2011-12-01 10:15:00'),0)
```

Será exibida a quantidade de minutos neste intervalo que é de 490 minutos.

**Converter minutos no formato HH:MM**

```
DECLARE @TMINUTOS INT 
SET @TMINUTOS=ISNULL(DATEDIFF(Mi,'2011-12-01 02:05:00','2011-12-01 10:15:00'),0)
```

A quantidade de minutos será 490 minutos

```
SELECT RIGHT('0' + CAST((@TMINUTOS / 60) As VARCHAR(2)),2) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CAST((@TMINUTOS % 60) As VARCHAR(2)),2)
```

O resultado a ser exibido é 08:10 que é a diferença dos horários.